# Recursive N-nested for loops with N assignments

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to do bitwise logical operations over a series of vectors. I think I need recursion, but I'm not sure how to get the recursion implemented and assign the values I need during recursion.

*Note: I know this is terribly slow and the complexity is not good, I'm researching probabilities of vector behavior for various logical operations.*

For a length of 4, I've got this to work, but how can I do this for any length? I've simplified the code so it is minimally reproducible.

```
DO = [137,80,78,71] #length of 4
values = np.zeros(len(DO), dtype=np.uint8)
vector_setS = np.zeros((len(DO)-2, 256, 8192), dtype=np.uint8)
A = np.ones(8192, dtype = np.uint8)
B = np.zeros(8192, dtype = np.uint8)

d = np.bitwise_and(A, B)
for vector_set in range(vector_setS.shape[0]-1):
    if vector_set == 0:
        r_range = range(256)
    else:
        r_range = [values[-(vector_set+2)]]
    for r in r_range:
        for a in range(256):
            d2 = np.bitwise_and(d, bitwise_and(vector_setS[vector_set, r], vector_setS[vector_set+1, a]))
            if d2.sum() == 0:
                values[-(vector_set+2)] = r
                values[-(vector_set+1)] = a
                break
```

As you can see, every time `DO` increases by one, a new for loop needs to be created to compare every vector in each `vector_set` to every other vector in each `vector_set`. AND I need to assign a new value to values when an event occurs. In this code, the event is `d2.sum == 0` where I want to store the indices of the vectors that made that possible.

Comment: I don't see recursion, but see several nested `for` loops. Those are slow - slower with numpy arrays than with lists.  Python isn't good for recursion,

Comment: @hpaulj the issue here is that as the length of `DO` grows, a new nested `for` loop is needed. Is this not recursion? I can appreciate your comment on lists over numpy arrays, but am also concerned with memory constraints and desire `np.uint8` types.